# Issue: Convert 12hr clock to 24 hrs, then reverse it back

Tags: c#, datetime

I am a c# beginner. I am writing a web application in MVP, and having trouble to convert 12 hr clock to 24 hr clock. 
So, there are three dropdown boxes (hour, mins, AM/PM)
When the AM/PM dropdown shows up as PM, the value of hour should be added by 12. Here is my code, but something wrong there.

```
public string sunOpenTime
{
    get
    {
        if (ddlSundayFrom.SelectedValue == "PM")
            return sunOpenTime = (ddlSundayOpenTimeHr.Text += 12) + ddlSundayOpenTimeMin.Text;
        else
            return sunOpenTime = ddlSundayOpenTimeHr.Text + ddlSundayOpenTimeMin.Text;
    }

    set
    {
        sunOpenTime = value;
    }
}
```

Another question  I have is, when the user click the existed record, the PM/AM dropdown should show up correctly on the web page. (If the record in the database is 18:00, then it should be 6:00 PM on the web page)
I am not very sure how to do that. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The error i guess is very obvious here due to your hour then you add minute ? 12 hour + 10 minute will become 22... Another thing is if i choose 12 pm it will become (12 + 12) becoming 24 + minute.. Still got 1 more error i guess you haven't convert it to integer and do a plus i don't think it will work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a code sample of how you could convert the time to 24 hour format if the time is in PM.
You could do the reverse, i.e. converting from 24 hours format to 12 hours format along similar lines as in the sample below & hence leave that to you. In case you want any help there, let me know.

**Code Sample: 12 hours to 24 hours**

```
public string sunOpenTime
{
    get
    {
        int hours = 0;
        int mins = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(ddlSundayOpenTimeHr.Text, hours) && int.TryParse(ddlSundayOpenTimeHr.Text, mins))
        {
            TimeSpan ts;
            if (ddlSundayFrom.SelectedValue == "PM")
            {
                ts = new TimeSpan(hours + 12, mins, 0);   
            }
            else
            {
                ts = new TimeSpan(hours, mins, 0);
            }
            return ts.ToString();//There are numerous ways to format the time string, check link below.
        }
        else
        {
                return "Invalid Time";//Indicatory msg - Handle it the way you want.
        }
    }

    set
    {
        sunOpenTime = value;
    }
}
```

P.S: Link for formatting time string is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT 1:**

You may consider moving the conversion code (12 hr to 24 hr) from the getter to a function or in any code block that suits you. In essence I'm trying to convey only the method of conversion from 12 hr to 24 hrs.

Comment: If selectedValue not equals to "PM" (I mean the else block), I think there is a little mistake :)  Because, if and else blocks are same...

Comment: @KemalKefeli: Copy paste can cause such subtle bugs. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @Ankit Thank you! I followed your way, and used TimeSpan. It seems work now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is some simple math you can do to convert between hours of a 24-hour clock and hours of a 12-hour clock.

```
// 24-hour clock to 12-hour clock
int hours12 = (hours24 + 11) % 12 + 1;
string meridiem = hours24 < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";

// 12-hour clock to 24-hour clock
int hours24 = meridiem == "AM"
  ? (hours12 == 12 ? 0 : hours12)
  : (hours12 == 12 ? 12 : hours12 + 12);
```